# Why is my for loop not working or is it something else that is causing problems?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

My question is not about the result of my function or loop being correct. It is about my loop not working no matter what I do.

What I tried to fix it myself:

1. I checked if html and JavaScript is linked correctly and if the function is triggered by the button called "Dreieck" at all. To check that I used `document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML="x";` right after the loop to see if it is generally working and it worked. That means after clicking on "Dreieck" an x appeared within the div with the id "ausgabe".
2. Then I thought maybe my loop isn't working because it is not getting any value from the variable "anzahlZeilen". So defined "i" as the following i=5. I actually changed the whole loop to a basic loop:

   ```
    for (var i=5; i==10; i++){
    document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML="x";
    }
   ```

So when I click on "Dreieck" there should appear an x again, but it didn't.

```js
function dreieck() {
    var anzahlZeilen= parseInt(document.getElementById("anzahlZeilen").value);
    var ausgabe="";
  
    for (var i= anzahlZeilen; i===0; i= i-1){
        ausgabe= ausgabe + (i*"*") + "</br>";
        document.getElementById("ausgabe").innerHTML=ausgabe;
    }
}
```

```css
div {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<label>Anzahl Zeilen:</label> </br>
<input type="number" id="anzahlZeilen"> </br>
<button type="button" onclick="dreieck();">Dreieck</button>
<button type="button" onclick="schachbrett();">Schachbrett</button>
<button type="button" onclick="baum();">Baum</button>
</br>
<div id="ausgabe"></div>

    <script src="js/Code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your input is not initialized to a number, so the value will not equal 0, unless the user changes it to zero.  So the loop will not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if your i equals 10 as a condition. This does not make sense, as you intialize it with a value of 5. As 5 does not equal ten, the condition for your loop to execute is not true from the beginning.

You probably want to check if i is smaller or equal to ten (i <= 10).

The logic is at follows:
Your loop does something while the condition after the for is true.
So at first you intialize a variable, that you want to use for counting. In this case, this is your i. You set it to a value of 5.

You then check if your loop condition is still true. If that is the case, you execute the body of the loop.

After that is done, you increment your i.

Without intializing the variable again, you then start over with checking if the condition is still true.

Comment: Where is the value initialized?  The input is not initialized at all

Comment: Ohhhhh, I thought it is the other way around and it must be false and is going on until it's true. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear! If my answer helped you, please consider giving it a vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong

```
for (var i= anzahlZeilen; i===0; i= i-1){
}
```

assigns `i` to `anzahlZeilen` (proably something > 0). The second part is the condition, ie  a check which is run on every iteration of the loop. The looping is stopped, when the condition returns false.

So when `anzahlZeilen` is greater than 0, the loop will immediately stop because `i === 0` returns false.

You probably want

```
for (var i= anzahlZeilen; i > 0; i= i-1){
}
```

Same for the other loop.

```
for (var i=5; i==10; i++)
```

You initialize `i = 5` and check `i == 10` immediately after, which obviously returns false, thus the loop stops. Again you want

```
for (var i= 5; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the loop in the first snippet of the OP doesn't make sense.  It will repeatedly set the html of the same element every time, because id lookups will always return the first match

Comment: @Taplar Yes, it will always set the same element, but it will always add something to the string content.

Comment: Add?  No.  Replace? Yes.  `=` is assignment/replacement, not appending.  `+= 'x'` would be appending

Comment: @Taplar `ausgabe = ausgabe + somethingelse` concatenates `ausgabe` and `somethingelse` and assigns the result to `ausgabe`. Thus, it's (well not technically, but semantically)  adding something to `ausgabe` ... At the end of the loop, `ausgabe` will contain the concatenated strings from all iterations, however you may like to call it ...

Comment: @derpirscher i'm not talking about that loop, I'm talking about the very first loop in the OP where the innerHTML is set to x.

Comment: @Taplar Obviously, even OP is aware of that, because he said in his question, that this loop is just a test ...

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. Really appreciate the conversation.